# Export rotated video out of Adobe Premiere

Tags: video, editing, premiere

I am creating a video in portrait orientation but the TV I am putting this on cannot rotate the video while playing, so I need to export the video in landscape format. Is there a way to rotate the video when exporting or rotate the entire sequence?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply transform the video to be vertical within the normal frame.  I'd do it using a nested sequence that way you can avoid having to alter your main full quality sequence.  Simply make a new scene, drag your existing scene in to it.  Click on the clip, go to Effects Control.  Expand Motion control and adjust the rotation, scale and position as necessary.